# Remove Characters From String which are not allowing string to pass a regex test

Tags: javascript, string

I am try to validate a string entered in a comment box against a REGEX pattern. My method looks like :

```
function skipMetadataSpecChar(val)
{
    if (val.match(/^[`_,:\057\134\075"';%@#!~\-\&\+\^\[\]\{\}\$\(\)\<\>\|\*\?\_\.,\s,0-9a-zA-Z]+$/)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

In one particular Scenario, when a user is pasting a string from somewhere else instead of typing it my method is returning false.
The Expected outcome should be the string by removing the characters not allowed in the regex.

**Sample String :**

This is test comment for the length of text as there was a issue in prod due to comment length in the box.This is test comment for the length of text as there was a issue in prod due to comment length in the box.This is test comment for the length of text as there was a issue in prod due to comment length in the box.This is test comment for the length of text as there was a issue in prod due to comment length in the box.This is test comment for the length of text as there was a issue in prod due to comment length in the box.This is test comment for the length of text as there was a issue in prod due to comment length in the box.This is test comment for the length of text as there was a issue in ﻁﻁﻉﻁﻉﻁﻉprod due to comment length in the box.This is test comment for the length of text as there was a issue in prod due to comment length in the box.;%@#This is test comment for the length of text as there was a issue in prod due to comment length in the box. This is test data to vhe issue an$

Comment: you may want to use [parsleyjs](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html)

Comment: So use [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)?